# Append only unlike data from one .csv to another .csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have managed to use Python with the speedtest-cli package to run a speedtest of my Internet speed. I run this every 15 min and append the results to a .csv file I call "speedtest.csv". I then have this .csv file emailed to me every 12 hours, which is a lot of data.

I am only interested in keeping the rows of data that return less than 13mbps Download speed. Using the following code, I am able to filter for this data and append it to a second .csv file I call `speedtestfilteronly.csv`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('c:\speedtest.csv', header=0)
df = df[df['Download'].map(lambda x: x < 13000000.0,)]
df.to_csv('c:\speedtestfilteronly.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

The problem now is it appends all the rows that match my filter criteria every time I run this code. So if I run this code 4 times, I receive the same 4 sets of appended data in the "speedtestfilteronly.csv" file.

I am looking to only append unlike rows from speedtest.csv to speedtestfilteronly.csv.

How can I achieve this?

I have got the following code to work, except the only thing it is not doing is filtering the results to < 13000000.0 mb/s: Any other ideas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:\speedtest.csv', header=0)  
df = df[df['Download'].map(lambda x: x < 13000000.0,)]

history_df = pd.read_csv('c:\speedtest.csv')
master_df = pd.concat([history_df, df], axis=0)
new_master_df = master_df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
new_master_df.to_csv('c:\emailspeedtest.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: How do you define 'unlike'? What's the criteria you would like it to select for?

Comment: I don't want the same rows matching the < 13mbps criteria appended to the .csv file from the last speedtests data. I only want the new speedtest data that matches the filtering criteria to append to the speedtestfilteronly.csv.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different way you could approach this, one would be  to read in your filtered dataset, append the new one in memory and then drop duplicates like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:\speedtest.csv', header=0)
df = df[df['Download'].map(lambda x: x < 13000000.0,)]

history_df = pd.read_csv('c:\speedtestfilteronly.csv', header=None)
master_df = pd.concat([history_df, df], axis=0)
new_master_df = master_df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
new_master_df.to_csv('c:\speedtestfilteronly.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

Comment: After running this, this is the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New.py", line 1, in <module>
    history_df = pd.read_csv('c:\speedtestfilteronly.csv', header=None)
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: looks like you don't have pandas imported in your session? `import pandas as pd`

Comment: You have the utmost patients for beginners. I thank you for that! When I run the code with
    import pandas as pd
at the top, I receive this error:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\New.py", line 3, in <module>
    master_df = pd.concat([history_df, df], axis=0)
NameError: name 'df' is not defined

Also, forgive me, but does the code also incorporate the filter for < 13mbps factor?

Comment: We were all beginners once! This was actually meant in addition to your existing code, I'll try to clarify in my answer

Comment: There are still a couple of things you will need to check with this code, for example does the file exist and do the columns read in as you expect (you may or may not have previously saved an index column), but it should get you on the way

Comment: After running my code and your code combined in one Python script. All the columns/rows/and field data are correct. However, I am still not getting rid of the duplicate rows. Is this due to me know saving an index column? I am not too aware of index columns, but I will research.

Comment: My suggestion is to check if history_df and df have the same number of columns and if they look how you expect, then line by line inspect the result, make sure you know what's going on and whether or not it's giving you the outcome you expect and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so speedtest.csv and speedtestfilteronly.csv have the same number of columns with the same headers. When I run the code, the results start at the very end of the last data set and one column over. This happens each time. The results are still duplicated data and it looks like stairs in speedtestfilteronly.csv. If my description makes any sense?

Comment: Not quite sure how this site works. I have edited my original post to include the working code, except for filtering. I couldn't get code block in the comment section. I don't know if you will be notified by me editing the main question, or only in comments section.